# Symfony: Redirect to user profile after login with id

Tags: php, symfony, twig

In my application I wish to redirect users to profile after login, so I'm using an hidden input with name `_target_path` and value `/profile/{userid}` in my TWIG page (I've tried to make an IF statement to check when the `app.user.username` variable exist, but this isn't the right logic)

```
<input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/profile/{% if app.user.username is defined %}{{ app.user.username }}{% endif %}" />
```

This isn't working as expected cause naturally when I render the form I've not already set the username in session.

Here is my `loginAction()` in AuthController.php

```
/**
 * @Route("login/", name="login")
 */
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render('auth/login.html.twig', array(
        'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        'error'         => $error,
    ));
}
```

I can reach the profile page using the parameter `ID`, so the url is like `example.com/profile/1` without the ID it's causing a 404.

So I need to redirect the user after login to `profile/{id}` taking it from `autenticationUtils`

I'm really sure that my logic is incorrect, but I can't find nothing in the web that can solve my issue.

Here is my security.yml

```
security:
  providers:
    user_db:
        entity: { class: AppBundle\Entity\User, property: username }

  encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt
        cost: 12

  firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login
        logout: true
        logout:
            csrf_parameter:       _csrf_token
            csrf_token_generator:  ~
            csrf_token_id:        logout
            path:                 /logout
            target:               /
            success_handler:      ~
            invalidate_session:   true
            delete_cookies:
                name:
                    path:                 null
                    domain:               null
            handlers:             []

    admin:
        pattern: ^/
        provider: user_db
        http_basic:
            realm: 'Admin Area'
            provider: in_memory
        form_login: ~



  access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/profilo, roles: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is changing the DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler (given you use the plain symfony mechanism wihtout any bundles like FOSUserBundle involved).

First thing make your own Handler (or parts, here especially onAuthenticationSuccess):

```
namespace ...

use ...

class AuthenticationSuccessHandler extends DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        **DO your logic here**

        //or call parent if you want default behaviour
        return parent::onAuthenticationSuccess($request, $token);
    }
}
```

Inject more services as needed.

Second overwrite the default service in your DI:

```
security.authentication.success_handler:
    class: AppBundle\Handler\AuthenticationSuccessHandler
    arguments: ['@security.http_utils', {}]
    tags:
        - { name: 'monolog.logger', channel: 'security' }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Symfony documentation: [Changing the default Page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login.html#changing-the-default-page)

### Changing the default Page:

First, the default page can be set (i.e. the page the user is redirected to if no previous page was stored in the session). To set it to the `default_security_target` route use the following config:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    # ...

    firewalls:
        main:
            form_login:
                # ...
                default_target_path: default_security_target
```

Now, when no URL is set in the session, users will be sent to the `default_security_target` route.

You can make it so that users are always redirected to the default page regardless of what URL they had requested previously by setting the `always_use_default_target_path` option to true:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    # ...

    firewalls:
        main:
            form_login:
                # ...
                always_use_default_target_path: true
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't see where to specify the current user ID.

Comment: You do not needs to specify the `user_id` in your routing. After logged in, the current user already stored in session. You can access it by call the method `getUser()` in your controller and global variable `app.user` in Twig. If you want to get current user in your service, just inject the `'security.token_storage'` service and get it.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this, can you explain how to do this in a reply? EDIT: I'm using the profile page to show every user profile, so an user can access the other profile easily using the ids. So I can't not use this

Comment: @andream If you want to expose you profile page to every user, yes, `user_id` needs to specify in your routing but not required. To satisfy your requirement, we've 2 ways to do that: 1. let the `user_id` optional, if the `user_id` from url is `null`, it's current logged in user. Otherwise, fetch the user from data using the given `user_id`. 2. `user_id` always required, as you explain abow. You need to create your own login success handler service. You can view the Symfony default handler for example `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler`.

Comment: @andream Then, add your service to security config: `success_handler: your.service.name`

Answer (score -1):

You should do something like this in PHP after login :

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('name_profile_route', { id : $this->getUser()->getId()});
```

Comment: Where should I put this?

Comment: After all the login process (password check...)

Comment: I think the login process is handled by symfony, I'm not sure where is this files. Sorry but I'm really new to this.

Comment: Are you using FOSUserBundle  or something like that ?

Comment: I don't think, but I'm not sure, I've follow the documentation guides. I've just updated my question including `security.yml`for reference